# AlarmManager - Am I doing it right?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

I had setup AlarmManager in my `MainActivity` class.

A class called `AlarmReceiver` gets fired up for every set interval of time.

I have to perform an operation when that class is fired up. That code is in in another class `Parsing.java`

Now in **AlarmReceiver.java**, I'm doing this :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Parsing obj = new Parsing(context);

        obj.execute();

    }
}
```

I cannot write the code directly in `AlarmReceiver.java`, because `AlarmReceiver.java` is already extending `BroadcastReceiver`and my code which is `Parsing.java` is extending another class.

So, I'm creating an object for `Parsing` class and calling that method.

Is my approach correct?

I'll furnish further information in case needed.
Please let me know if my approach is correct?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

**Parsing.java**

```
public class Parsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//some code

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting an `AsyncTask` from a `BroadcastReceiver` is wrong for two reasons:

**1.** The thread on which `onReceive()` runs is terminated after the method returns, effectively ending any long-running task which may have been started from there. To quote the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> A `BroadcastReceiver` object is only valid for the duration of the
>   call to `onReceive(Context, Intent)`. Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active ..... anything that requires asynchronous operation is not
>   available, because you will need to return from the function to handle
>   the asynchronous operation, but at that point the `BroadcastReceiver`
>   is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process
>   before the asynchronous operation completes.

**2.** The `Context` instance that `onReceive()` provides is not the same as
the `Context` of an `Activity` or `Service`, i.e. `Activity.this` or 
`Service.this`. You need that proper `Context` for performing many of
the common useful operations that we usually do from an `Activity` or
`Service`. So, for example, the correct way to start a `Service` in
`onReceive()` is:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ParsingService.class);
    context.getApplicationContext().startService(i);
}
```

and not

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ParsingService.class);
    context.startService(i);
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! But considering the first reason you stated, does the service which we start from 'onReceive()' get terminated after sometime i.e. after the code returns from this function?

Comment: No, the `Service` is a completely independent component which does not have anything to do with the lifecycle of your `BroadcastReceiver` ... so you should not worry about that. The `Service` can be stopped after it finishes its work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you wrote your Parsing.java, it looks fine but remember this

> This method is always called within the main thread of its process, unless you explicitly asked for it to be scheduled on a different thread using registerReceiver. When it runs on the main thread you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed). You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation of onReceive()

To me, i think it's a better way to handle this is calling another service inside onReceive method, like this

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ParsingService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
```

Comment: By starting another service, are we removing that time constraint?

Comment: Please look at my edited question, I added Parsing.java class.